# C# XAML and Code isses

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to finish off this program but I have a few errors that I can't get rid of. I've been following the C# book I have as well, and I can't seem to find missing steps. I'll post the XAML code and the regular code.

[image: Heres a picture of the application, if it helps anyone understand more of what I'm doing.]

Errors I have are as followed...

- Warning   3   Unreachable code detected
- Error 1   The type or namespace name 'memberSince' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error 4   The type or namespace name 'Member' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error 5   The type or namespace name 'Member' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error 6   Delegate 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart' does not take 0 arguments
- Error 2   'BellRingers.MainWindow.memberSince' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BellRingers.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Middleshire Bell Ringers Association - Members" Height="470" Width="600" Closing="Window_Closing">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="bellRingersFontStyle" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="bellRingersStyle" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="textBoxMenu" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" >
        <MenuItem Header="Clear Name" Name="clearName" Click="clearName_Click" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Image Panel.ZIndex="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="image1" >
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="bell.gif" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
    <Label Content="First Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,25,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,25,0,0" Name="firstName" ContextMenu="{StaticResource textBoxMenu}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersStyle}" IsEnabled="False" />
    <Label Content="Last Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,25,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,25,0,0" Name="lastName" ContextMenu="{StaticResource textBoxMenu}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersStyle}" IsEnabled="False" />
    <Label Content="Tower" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,72,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,72,0,0" Name="towerNames" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" IsEnabled="False" />
    <CheckBox Content="Captain" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="420,72,0,0" Name="isCaptain" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" IsEnabled="False" />
    <Label Content="Member Since" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,134,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" />
    <DatePicker Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,134,0,0" Name="memberSince" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" IsEnabled="False" />
    <GroupBox Header="Experience" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,174,0,0" Name="yearsExperience" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" IsEnabled="False">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="stackPanel1">
            <RadioButton Content="Up to 1 year" Height="16" Name="novice" Width="120" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" />
            <RadioButton Content="1 to 4 years" Height="16" Name="intermediate" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
            <RadioButton Content="5 to 9 years" Height="16" Name="experienced" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
            <RadioButton Content="10 or more" Height="16" Name="accomplished" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <ListBox Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,174,0,0" Name="methods" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" IsEnabled="False" />
    <Button Content="Clear" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="313,378,0,0" Name="clear" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersStyle}" Click="clear_Click" IsEnabled="False" />
    <DockPanel Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
        <Menu Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" Height="23" Name="menu1" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New Member" Name="newMember" Click="newMember_Click" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Face.bmp" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save Member Details" Name="saveMember" IsEnabled="False" Click="saveMember_Click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Note.bmp" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="E_xit" Name="exit" Click="exit_Click"  />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_About Middleshire Bell Ringers" Name="about" Click="about_Click" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Ring.bmp" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
    <StatusBar Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="status" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string[] towers = { "Great Shevington", "Little Mudford", 
                                "Upper Gumtree", "Downley Hatch" };

    private string[] ringingMethods = {"Plain Bob", "Reverse Canterbury",
        "Grandsire", "Stedman", "Kent Treble Bob", "Old Oxford Delight",
        "Winchendon Place", "Norwich Suprise", "Crayford Little Court" };

    private ContextMenu windowContextMenu = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Reset();

        MenuItem saveMemberMenuItem = new MenuItem();
        saveMemberMenuItem.Header = "Save Member Details";
        saveMemberMenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(saveMember_Click);

        MenuItem clearFormMenuItem = new MenuItem();
        clearFormMenuItem.Header = "Clear Form";
        clearFormMenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(clear_Click);

        windowContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        windowContextMenu.Items.Add(saveMemberMenuItem);
        windowContextMenu.Items.Add(clearFormMenuItem);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        firstName.Text = String.Empty;
        lastName.Text = String.Empty;

        towerNames.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string towerName in towers)
        {
            towerNames.Items.Add(towerName);
        }
        towerNames.Text = towerNames.Items[0] as string;

        methods.Items.Clear();
        CheckBox method = null;
        foreach (string methodName in ringingMethods)
        {
            method = new CheckBox();
            method.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10);
            method.Content = methodName;
            methods.Items.Add(method);
        }

        isCaptain.IsChecked = false;
        novice.IsChecked = true;
        memberSince.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString();
    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Reset();
    }

    //private void add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    string nameAndTower = String.Format(
    //        "member name: {0} {1} from the tower at {2} rings the following methods:",
    //        firstName.Text, lastName.Text, towerNames.Text);

    //    StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder();
    //    details.AppendLine(nameAndTower);

    //    foreach (CheckBox cb in methods.Items)
    //    {
    //        if (cb.IsChecked.Value)
    //        {
    //            details.AppendLine(cb.Content.ToString());
    //        }
    //    }

    //    MessageBox.Show(details.ToString(), "Member Information");
    //}

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult key = MessageBox.Show(
            "Are you sure you want to quit",
            "Confirm",
            MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
            MessageBoxImage.Question,
            MessageBoxResult.No);
        e.Cancel = (key == MessageBoxResult.No);
    }

    private void newMember_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Reset();
        saveMember.IsEnabled = true;
        firstName.IsEnabled = true;
        lastName.IsEnabled = true;
        towerNames.IsEnabled = true;
        isCaptain.IsEnabled = true;
        memberSince.IsEnabled = true;
        yearsExperience.IsEnabled = true;
        methods.IsEnabled = true;
        clear.IsEnabled = true;

        this.ContextMenu = windowContextMenu;
    }

    private void exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void saveData(string fileName, memberSince member)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("First Name: {0}", member.FirstName);
            writer.WriteLine("Last Name: {0}", member.LastName);
            writer.WriteLine("Tower: {0}", member.TowerName);
            writer.WriteLine("Captain: {0}", member.IsCaptain.ToString());
            writer.WriteLine("Member Since: {0}", member.MemberSince.ToString());
            writer.WriteLine("Methods: ");
            foreach (string method in member.Methods)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(method);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Action action = new Action(() =>
            {
                status.Items.Add("Member details saved");
            });
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
        }
    }

    private void saveMember_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveDialog.DefaultExt = "txt";
        saveDialog.AddExtension = true;
        saveDialog.FileName = "Members";
        saveDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\John\Documents";
        saveDialog.OverwritePrompt = true;
        saveDialog.Title = "Bell Ringers";
        saveDialog.ValidateNames = true;
        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog().Value)
        {
            Member member = new Member();
            member.FirstName = firstName.Text;
            member.LastName = lastName.Text;
            member.TowerName = towerNames.Text;
            member.IsCaptain = isCaptain.IsChecked.Value;
            member.MemberSince = memberSince.SelectedDate.Value;
            member.Methods = new List<string>();
            foreach (CheckBox cb in methods.Items)
            {
                if (cb.IsChecked.Value)
                {
                    member.Methods.Add(cb.Content.ToString());
                }
            }

            Thread workerThread = new Thread(
                () => this.saveData(saveDialog.FileName, member));
            workerThread.Start();
        }
    }

    private void about_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        About aboutWindow = new About();
        aboutWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void clearName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        firstName.Clear();
        lastName.Clear();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How about the errors / problems that you state that you have. Please edit your question to add them.

Comment: Its not letting me post both code and xaml at the same time I dont think. Keeps giving me edit errors I can't change. Too long for comments.

Comment: You should be able to, try to get it into your question I will edit. It looks like most of your problems are in your code behind, try posting that.

Comment: There, figured it out!

Comment: I don't see where you are creating your `member` Type

Comment: `member` is defined as a type of `memberSince`. Where is the class definition for `memebrSince`?

Comment: @aks81 he also is creating a member from a structure called Member, which I don't see either.  `Member member = new Member();`

Comment: So now we know Error 1,2,4,5.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mistake is here:

```
private void saveData(string fileName, memberSince member)
{
        ...
}
```

in the saveData method definition you specify **"memberSince"** as a parameter type,but it is your **DatePicker** name,not a type.

and second mistake i can't see your Member class definition too,check these issues and come again.

edit- solution:

Change your saveData method definition like this replace **memberSince** with **Member**:

```
private void saveData(string fileName, Member member)
{
    ...
}
```

And make sure you define your Member class.

Comment: Then he needs to change the signature to just `saveData(string fileName)` and instead use the `memberSince` directly.

Comment: I can't see where I messed up. I'm looking but I can't figure it out. Do I need a new class or what, if so where do I put it? Am I maybe missing from the XAML.

Comment: Where is the definition for `Member` class?

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more attributes to your DatePicker field in xaml

```
<DatePicker x:Name="memberSince" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,134,0,0" Name="memberSince" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" IsEnabled="False" />
```

Then in you code behind you can directly access `memberSince` directly. That is your Error 2. You need to do this changes to all fields necessary

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Structure called Member, something like this:

```
struct Member
{
   public string FirstName;
   public string LastName;
   public string TowerName;
   public bool IsCaptain;
   public DateTime MemberSince;
   public List<string> Methods;

}
```

then change your the saveData Method's signature to this.

```
private void saveData(string fileName, Member member)
{  ...
```

Doing this cleared all of the errors for me.

Comment: Oh you created a structure definition for him. Great

Comment: @aks81 all of the errors were directly attributed to not have the structure.

Comment: The other mess up was he did was the `fieldName` in the code behind inadvertently matched the field names in the xaml

Comment: @aks81 Actually, that may be but the only change I made was what I posted, I can create a Member and save it, using his code.